# principal axis of a volume from moments of inertia

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I'm trying to calculate the expression to find the principal axis of a volume via its moments. In the 2D case I can formulate the problem by expressing the moments around arbitrary axes

$x' = x \cos A + y \sin A$

$y' = y \cos A - x \sin A$

The moments $I_{x'}$ and $I_{x'y'}$ and also $I_{y'}$ and $I_{x'y'}$ are then considered to be the parametric equations of $2$ circles both defined as:

$$
(I_{x'} - I_\text{ave})^2 + I_{x'y'}^2 = R^2\\
$$

where $I_\text{ave} = (I_x+I_y)/2$.

so that $R = \sqrt{(I_x-I_y)/2 + I_{xy}^2}$.

This somehow leads to the equation for the angle of the principal axis as being $\arctan\left(\frac{2Ixy}{Ix - Iy}\right)/2$.

In the 3D case I can formulate the 2nd order moments in terms of arbitrary axes $x', y', z'$ which are very long expressions (which is why I'm not pasting them here) but I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot you use the definition? The principal axes are the directions of the eigenvectors of the inertia matrix.

Comment: I guess I could use PCA to find the orientation but I'm trying to find a more computationally efficient solution.